# SVN conflicts from files I never even touched

Tags: svn

1. After finishing my work with my branch, I commit my work.  Now I'm
   at r1234.
2. Then I sync trunk with `svn merge ^/trunk/foo/myproject`.
   It works. I commit. Now I'm at r1235.
3. I find out that I commited something for developping purposes only in step 2. 
   I used `svn merge -r 1235:1234 .` to revert the sync. I commit. Now I'm at r1236.
4. `svn diff -r1234 .` shows nothing, which is good. Now I run `svn merge ^/trunk/foo/myproject` to sync with trunk. This time a lot conflicts come up

> Summary of conflicts:
>
> Text conflicts: 12
>
> Tree conflicts: 21

Now I can get back to r1236 with `svn revert -R .` But what should I do to sync with trunk?

Edit:

I copied r1234 to a new branch.  Then I run `svn merge ^/trunk/foo/myproject`.  There are still many conflicts.  Is this normal?

More Edit:

Seems a previous sync is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conflicts logically occurred because you have already performed the merge on rev 1235, and also modified the same files on rev 1236.
What I suggest to re-do your merge from trunk to branch is to:
    - create a patch file using svn diff command (on trunk: diff between the revision of the branch creation and HEAD revision)
    - apply this patch on your branch

Comment: Thanks! I thought `svn` could automatically figure out what have been merged

Comment: Still I have one more question.  Please have a look?

Comment: @zjk How did you copy r1234 to a new branch ? Did you use the "svn copy" command ?

Comment: Yes I used `svn cp https:/url/mybranch`.  It seems that an older sync trunk commit is problematic.